# Given an unordered list of n-dimensional points, how can I best find the smallest volume defined by n+1 of those points that encloses a given point?

Tags: algorithm, geometry

*Note: I'm very much from a programming background, not a mathematics background. This will become obvious very quickly.*

Assume I have a bounded n-dimensional space - for example here I'll use n=2. In that space, I have a set of pre-defined points. (As it happens, I'm doing something questionable with genetic algorithms for finding minima in non-mathematically-solvable equations, but that's not directly relevant).

Next, I have defined a new point within that 2D space. I want to know which three (n+1) points form the smallest (or possibly nearest?) triangle that contains that point. Illustration here:

[image: img]

Now, as that illustration shows, I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing, in that I've failed to adequately describe the criteria by which the candidate triangles are judged - points 10, 5, and 8 would enclose the point within a triangle of smaller area, for example. This is because those specifics are somewhat flexible. What I really care about is:

- Computational efficiency: I could potentially end up scaling this algorithm up to thousands of points in a hundred dimensions. As such, I need a solution that's better than exhaustively testing every potential convex hull against a specific equation, and ideally one with a decent big-O notation. Presumably I'm going to need a more intelligent structure that a big unordered list to do this.
- If I had a preferred criteria, it's proximity of the hull vertices to the test point. However, if it's easier to build an algorithm which judges by area/volume or something else, I can live with that.
- I need to be able to handle edge-cases, where the test-point is, for example, on the edge between two vertices.

Where do I even start with this? Some cursory googling suggests Voronoi diagrams might be a step in the right direction, is that correct? What are the right tools for this job? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _want to know which three (n+1) points form the smallest (or possibly nearest?) triangle that contains that point_ Which three of `n` existing points form the smallest by area triangle containing the given point? Or something else?

Comment: lookup the notion of space aware datastructures ... depending on which N dimension ... in 2 dimensions its called quad tree ... in 3D its octrees ... its the same approach in N dim ... since as you say these points are predefined so prepocess by populating the datastructure with each of your points then just query the datastructure to identify sibling points sharing same quadrant

Comment: In general, you want to identify the simplex of a Delaunay triangulation in _d_ dimensions  that contains a/some given point(s). This triangulation is unique for a given point set. The triangulation can be computed in a preprocessing step. Certain scientific programming languages (Matlab, GNU Octave) and scientific computing libraries like scipy for Python contain routines to compute the triangulation and query the simplex. Hope that gets you started.

Comment: In your example image, the P8,P5,P10 triangle has a smaller area.  Are you sure "smallest volume" is what you want?

Comment: What do you know about the points? like average and smallest density ... spatially sorted points allow using binary search instead of linear and spatial organizations can get you all point "nearby" directly both  allowing huge speed ups ... so you could obtain all close enough points to your NEW and then just test all possible simplexes using greedy criteria... lowering your thousands of points to some manageable number ...